# Eclipse NDK Build for Nougat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I want to create an NDK app that works in Nougat.
I'm trying to create an **NDK app** that works in **Nougat** with **eclipse**.

I tested it in various versions but it failed. Anyone know any possible way?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing what "it failed" means. Also, please note that Eclipse support from Google ended ~9 months ago.

Comment: I tried to make environment each versions many times.
 eclipse neon2, 3 / JDK 1.7, 1.8 / Android SDK r24.4.1, Lastest Version.

I didn't record the failed log.
I will try again for the log.
Thank you.

Comment: Eclipse hasn't been supported by Android for ages. Odds are the new tools don't work with it.